# MYSQL: How to update the field according to it's partner (id), so the data not updated to all rows?

Tags: mysql

Based on the tabel below, it is shown that the data (SJ000001) on field `no_sj` wrote on all rows, i want SJ000001 is only for FA000005.

```
no_fab  | date     | kd_plg | kd_paket | no_sj
FA000001 dd/mm/yyyy   plg001   pk001    SJ000001
FA000002 dd/mm/yyyy   plg002   pk002    SJ000001
FA000003 dd/mm/yyyy   plg003   pk003    SJ000001
FA000004 dd/mm/yyyy   plg004   pk004    SJ000001
FA000005 dd/mm/yyyy   plg005   pk005    SJ000001
```

That table above is from this query:

```
UPDATE fab SET fab.no_sj=? WHERE no_fab=?
```

So how to do the right query?

EDIT:

It's hard to explain it in English, but I will try to explain it. So actually this data come from `visual studio .NET textboxt` form as I am sure, that the visual studio codes doesn't matter on this false. But, this is the actual cases, I have a table named fab. That table above is 'fab' which is the no_sj at first time is NULL, to make it show the data I have to update it using `VS.NET` form, and after I tried the `SQL` syntax above, I got that problem.

Comment: Aside from the `?` your update statement seems fine, please provide a complete working test case.

Comment: You should edit the question to include the table structure *in the query* (as a text table, for formatting just put four spaces in front of each line).  Links may not always be available.

Comment: It's hard to explain it in english, but i will try to explain it.
So actually this data come from visual studio .NET textboxt form as i am sure, that the visual studio codes doesn't matter on this false. 
But, this is the actual cases, i have a tabel named `fab`. That tabel above is 'fab' which is the `no_sj` at first time is NULL, to make it show the data i have to update it using VS.NET form, and after i tried the SQL syntax above, i got that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify a condition in your WHERE clause to reference to the row you want to update. It is as simple as:

```
UPDATE fab SET no_sj='SJ000001' WHERE no_fab='FA000005'
```

If you were looking to have SJ000001 relate to FA000001 and SJ000002 relate to FA000002, etc. Then go with:

```
UPDATE fab SET no_sj=CONCAT('SJ',RIGHT(no_fab,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR INSPIRING ME mark_matters, though it's not just `UPDATE fab SET no_sj='SJ000001' WHERE no_fab='FA000005'` but i modified it because i actually using vs.net to update the data so i made this simple sub to be called on the button that worked as update button:

```
Sub update_no_sj_on_fab()
    Dim xupdate As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim xmycmd As OdbcCommand
    xubah = "UPDATE fab SET fab.no_sj=? WHERE no_fab='" & txtno_fab.Text & "'"

    xmycmd = New OdbcCommand(xupdate, Mycn)
    xmycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("no_sj", txtno_sj.Text)

    xmycmd.Prepare()
    x = xmycmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    xmycmd.Dispose()
    Return

End Sub
```